# Editing Devise From Users#show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a Rails 3.2 application that uses Devise for authentication. Currently, the `new_user_registration` works fine and the `edit_user_registration` paths both work as designed. However, I have designed a tabbed user profile where the user will have access to various forms (edit registration, site settings etc.)

**The Issue**

Although the `users#show` page contains a partial that pulls in the form for editing registration, it doesn't actually allow the user to edit. I would just recreate an `edit` action in the users controller, but I want to keep some of Devise's built in functionality (such as lost password, etc. not sure if this is effected).

Is there any way I can I have the user edit `registrations#edit` action on the `users#show` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll can override Devise's default behavior to get this to work. Start by bringing your `show` action into the Devise `RegistrationsController`, then declaring a route to the action:

```
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def show
    end     
end

# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }  
devise_scope :user do
  get "users/show"=> "users/registrations#show", :as => "show_registration"
end
```

Then, in your `RegistrationsController#show` action, create an instance of `resource` to pass to the view:

```
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def show
        self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    end
```

Finally, add a form to your `show.html.erb` view that will submit to the `RegistrationsController#update` action. You can copy this directly from the [default Devise `registration/edit.html.erb` template](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
end
```

Voilà! Your custom `show` action will contain a form that submits the current registrations resource to the default Devise `RegistrationsController#update` action.

Comment: Sure, please apprise as to whether it works... I haven't actually implemented it myself.